# How do I get a link in Bootstrap nav bar to disappear/reappear based on window size?

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm currently building a website using Bootstrap. I have a "Services" link listed in my nav bar, that when hovered over displays a list of services. The user can also click on "Services" itself and they are directed to a link. If the user resizes their screen, or are looking at the website on their mobile device, I need to be able to remove the link from "Services".

The code below sort of works. I am running into a bug when I try to resize the desktop browser multiple times. Once I make the screen smaller, I am unable to recognize a larger browser window and, therefore, get the link in "Services" back. What am I missing?

HTML

```
<li class="dropdown">
    <a href="#services" class="dropdown-toggle linkedDropDown" data-toggle="dropdown">Services
         <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i>
    </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
         <li>
              <a href="">Link 1</a>
         </li>
         <li>
              <a href="">Link 2</a>
         </li>
         <li>
              <a href="">Link 3</a>
         </li>
         <li>
              <a href="">Link 4</a>
         </li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

CSS

```
@media (min-width:990px){
    .dropdown:hover .dropdown-menu {
        display: block !important;
        margin-top: 0 !important;
     }
}
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     changeElements();

     $(window).resize(function() {
          changeElements();
     });
 });

function changeElements(){
     if ($(window).width() < 990) {
           $('.linkedDropDown').removeAttr('href');
     }
     else{
           $('.linkedDropDown').attr('href');  
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Bootstrap you can add the `d-*-none` class to hide elements at a certain pixel width, or `d-*-block` to show elements at a particular pixel width.

For example, if you wanted to hide the "Services" link on mobile devices, you could add the classes `d-none` and `d-sm-block` to your link tag.  This will hide the link when then screen width is less than 544px but show it on all larger screen sizes.

By adding these classes there will be no need for your current JavaScript.

More documentation on the responsive utility classes can be found here: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/migration/#responsive-utilities

Answer (score 0):

check by removing the data-toggle attribute and change the classes for the screen on which you don't need the dropdown. Hope this should work